# Set all values to None for multiple columns

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I'm setting up a Spark batch that aims to filter out some fields that need cleaning up. How do I set the columns in question's values to None for all rows ? (I already have a dataframe containing only rows I want to alter)

I am far from an expert in Spark, and I searched around a lot before asking here, but I am still at loss for a simple enough answer.

There are around 50 columns, and I cannot hard-code the column index to access it, as it may change in future batches.

### Example Input dataframe (target columns contain data):

```
id        TARGET 1       TARGET 2       TARGET 3     Col6     ...
someid1   Some(String)   Some(String)   Some(String) val1     ...
someid2   Some(String)   Some(String)   None         val4     ...
someid5   Some(String)   Some(String)   Some(String) val3     ...
someid6   Some(String)   Some(String)   Some(String) val7     ...
```

### Expected Output dataframe (all target columns set to None):

```
id        TARGET 1       TARGET 2       TARGET 3     Col6     ...
someid1   None           None           None         val1     ...
someid2   None           None           None         val4     ...
someid5   None           None           None         val3     ...
someid6   None           None           None         val7     ...
```

Comment: Can it be null instead of None ?

Comment: The fields in question are Option[String], so we do need them to be None and not Nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Spark doesn't accept None values. A possible solution would be to replace them with null values casted to String :

```
ds.
  .withColumn("target1", lit(null).cast(StringType))
  .withColumn("target2", lit(null).cast(StringType))
```

It produces the following output :

```
+--------------------+-------+-------+-----+
|                  id|target1|target2| col6|
+--------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| 4201735573065099460|   null|   null|疦薠紀趣餅|
|-6432819446886055080|   null|   null|┵િ塇駢뱪|
|-7700306868339925800|   null|   null|鵎썢鳝踽嬌|
|-4913818084582557950|   null|   null|ꢵ痩찢쑖|
| 6731176796531697018|   null|   null|少⽬ᩢゖ謹|
+--------------------+-------+-------+-----+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- target1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- target2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col6: string (nullable = true)
```

That's also what you get when you set a value to `None` in a Dataset.

```
case class TestData(id: Long, target1: Option[String], target2: Option[String], col6: String)

val res = Seq(
  TestData(1, Some("a"), Some("b"), "c"),
  TestData(2, Some("a"), Some("b"), "c"),
  TestData(3, Some("a"), Some("b"), "c"),
  TestData(4, Some("a"), Some("b"), "c")
).toDS()

res.show(5)
res.map(_.copy(target1 = None, target2 = None)).show(5)
res.printSchema()
```

Will returns :

```
+---+-------+-------+----+
| id|target1|target2|col6|
+---+-------+-------+----+
|  1|      a|      b|   c|
|  2|      a|      b|   c|
|  3|      a|      b|   c|
|  4|      a|      b|   c|
+---+-------+-------+----+

+---+-------+-------+----+
| id|target1|target2|col6|
+---+-------+-------+----+
|  1|   null|   null|   c|
|  2|   null|   null|   c|
|  3|   null|   null|   c|
|  4|   null|   null|   c|
+---+-------+-------+----+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- target1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- target2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col6: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Using Datasets may be my solution indeed. I'm off to test it out !